# how can we capture the nested elements in an xml?

Tags: c#, xml, interop, excel-interop

I am trying to capture the sub-container information from the following XML using the tag subcontainer however I don't want the nested subcontainers to be captured. how can I do this?

```
<sub-container>
   <name>subcont1</name>
   <name>subcont2</name>
   <name>subcont3</name>
      <sub-container>
         <name>subcont31</name>
         <name>subcont32</name>
      </sub-container>
   <name>subcont4</name>
</sub-container>
```

I tried getting the elements by tag name and checked whether their parent node is a sub-container. the nested subcontainers were also captured. I actually want them to be captured in Excel in a different column

Comment: Can you format your XML? Can you also present valid XML (at the very least, a fragment with a single root element). What have ypu tried, and what did you get (and what did you expect)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this in C# using LINQ to XML:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

string xml = @"
<root>
  <sub-container>
    <name>subcont1</name>
    <name>subcont2</name>
    <name>subcont3</name>
      <sub-container>
         <name>subcont31</name>
         <name>subcont32</name>
      </sub-container>
    <name>subcont4</name>
  </sub-container>
</root>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var topLevelSubcontainers = doc.Descendants("sub-container")
                                .Where(x => x.Parent == doc.Root);

foreach (var subcont in topLevelSubcontainers)
{
    foreach (var name in subcont.Elements("name"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```